# VSCode Include path C++

Tags: c++, path, include, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn C++, but I am having trouble. When trying to compile my source file, I receive the below error message for all of my header files.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried adding multiple paths to my CPP properties file but am still having trouble identifying the problem.

[image]

Above is the properties file I previously mentioned.

[image]

Also, here is how my directory is set up. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is `"Book.h"`? is that a header file that you created, or is it part of a predefined library?

Comment: It looks like you have "`book.h`" defined in your headers directory, which the header directory looks like its sitting in the same level as the source directory where your `"main.cpp"` file is. If that is the case, use the following: `#include "../Book.h"`

Comment: And let me know if it works. If it doesn't it might be because of the compiler instructions you have, or haven't, added to the header document.

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV Abdul answered my question correctly but thank you for your input.

Comment: Abdul just repeated what I had already said to do.

Comment: Considering this was caused by a typo, an incorrect file-path, I'm flagging to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I am able to understand, you are trying to run main.cpp that has a user defined header file Book.h
But Book.h is in another directory so, try using

```
#include "../headers/Book.h"
```

Basically you need to give the location of Book.h file in respect to main.cpp